# Modifying the output based on column value : SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have below table[image]

I want to create a SQL query to create a field which will concatenate the field's name with first column wherever we have the value "Yes" and only show one value in one row -

Output should be like this

```
James|Denver
James|Houston
James|Orlando
Williom|Denver
Williom|Houston
Ron|Chicago
Ron|Dallas
Ron|Austin
Saviz|Chicago
Saviz|Houston
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is column list static?  I.e.6 cities only?

Comment: yes its static. It will be only 6 cities

Comment: Can anyone help for this question?

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query like below with case and coalesce

```
select NAME,coalesce(case when Chicago="Yes" then "Chicago" else null end,
case when Denver="Yes" then "Denver" else null end,
case when Dallas="Yes" then "Dallas" else null end,
case when Houston="Yes" then "Houston" else null end,
case when Austin="Yes" then "Austin" else null end,
case when Orlando="Yes" then "Orlando" else null end) from tdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cities as
(
    select 'chicago'   city union all
    select 'denver' union all
    select 'dallas' union all
    select 'houston' union all
    select 'austin' union all
    select 'orlando'
), 
user_data as
(
    select 'James'   name, 'NO' chicago, 'Yes' denver, 'NO' dallas, 'Yes' houston, 'NO' austin, 'Yes' orlando union all
    select 'Williom' name, 'NO' chicago, 'Yes' denver, 'NO' dallas, 'Yes' houston, 'NO' austin, 'NO' orlando union all
    select 'Ron'     name, 'Yes'chicago, 'NO'  denver, 'Yes'dallas, 'NO'  houston, 'Yes'austin, 'NO' orlando union all
    select 'Savis'   name, 'Yes'chicago, 'NO'  denver, 'NO' dallas, 'Yes' houston, 'NO' austin, 'NO' orlando
)
select user_data_normalized.name,
       cities.city
from
(
    select name, 'chicago' city, chicago attr from user_data union all
    select name, 'denver', denver from user_data union all
    select name, 'dallas', dallas from user_data union all
    select name, 'houston', houston from user_data union all
    select name, 'austin', austin from user_data union all
    select name, 'orlando', orlando from user_data
) user_data_normalized
join cities on cities.city = user_data_normalized.city
where user_data_normalized.attr = 'Yes'
order by 1,2
```